# JSON Schema : required properties ignored

Tags: php, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I discovered JSON Schema today it looks to be 100% fitting my needs, but it's actually driving me nuts with one of the most basic cases. Before creating this post, I obviously did my best to follow existing documentation and looked on the internet trying to find something helping.

Stack : PHP7 - justinrainbow/json-schema 2.0.5

Here is the schema :

```
{
   "description":"UserCreate",
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "login":{
         "type":"string",
         "required":true
      },
      "idAsc":{
         "type":"string",
         "required":true
      }
   },
   "required":[
      "login",
      "idAsc"
   ]
}
```

As you can see I am using both required definition (boolean and array), just to be sure I am using the good one, I also tried with only array and or boolean with the same result.

Here is the data

```
{
   "login":"email@email.com"
}
```

I am expecting the following code to detect the lack of the required idAsc parameter.

```
$validator = new JsonSchema\Validator;
$validator->check($data, $schema);
if ($validator->isValid() == false)
    echo("Missing something");
else
    echo("Good");
```

But this code keep printing "Good”… I am definitely missing something about JSON Schema.

Thank's for your help, best regards.

Comment: http://json-schema.org/implementations.html lists 5 different JSON Schema validators for PHP. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Barmar You can found it in my "stack" section : Actually working with justinrainbow/json-schema -> https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally make it work, after debugging step by step the implementation of JSON Schema I was using :

First of all, I loaded the JSON Schema myself, the example given in the Github repo look to be broken for me (https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'));

// Validate
$validator = new JsonSchema\Validator;
$validator->check($data, (object)['$ref' => 'file://' . realpath('schema.json')]);
```

I was not able to find any call to file_get_contents or relatives inside the library during my step by step debug. For this reason I decided to load the schema myself instead of giving the path to it:

```
function getSchema($filePath) {
   // NOT WORKING -> return json_decode(file_get_contents($filePath), true);
   return json_decode(file_get_contents($filePath));
}

$data = json_decode($rest->getRequest()->getBody());
$schema = $this->getSchema(realpath('controllers/schemas/userCreate.json'));

$validator = new JsonSchema\Validator;
$check_return = $validator->check($data, $schema);
```

Please pay attention to the commented line in the getSchema function, if you use json_decode with true as 2nd parameter it's not going to work either, the schema has to be an object and not an array !

Now everything is working like a charm for me ;)

Best regards,

Comment: I decided to create a ticket to owners of the library to ask for more details :
https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema/issues/299

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue of the validator implementation you use. This validation must fail. You can try it out with other implementations.

Comment: This is going to be one of my tasks this morning, but it seems weird to me ... I used the most popular implementation according to the number of contributors on Github.

Comment: what happens if you remove the `"required":true` properties from the property definitions? That property doesn't violate the schema spec, but also doesn't have any effect, though still cause unexpected behavior for the schema impl. I would give it a go.

Comment: I tried it even before the creation of this post, but you are right this required is not following the v4 of JSON Schema definition. I finally fix this, feel free to read my last post, where I explained a bit what I did to make it work.